# JavaScript : Pass-by-reference issues when creating an unknown dimension multi dimensional array function

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, dynamically-generated

I'm posting this question because I am trying to make a function that allows someone to create a multi-dim array. So, the user inputs an array of numbers which are the dimensions of the array (e.g entering `[2, 4, 3]` would output a 2x4x3 multi-dim array)
I have spent a couple of hours trying to imagine an algorithm that can do this in JS and I came up with this:

Note: I use Node.js v9.11.1

```
function generate(dimensions) {

  // SA = sub-array (I will use this several times here)

  // This array will store every SAs of the multi-dim array
  // E.g for a 2x4x3 array, it will store a 2-item array, a 4-item array and a 3-item array
  var arrays = []

  // This fills `arrays` with the SAs
  for (var i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++) arrays.push(new Array(dimensions[i]).slice(0))

  // Here it gets a bit complex (at least for me!)
  // So what we do is that for each SA (except last), we fill it with copies of the current+1 SA
  // So the SA at index 1 will be filled with copies of the array at index 2
  // And the array at index 0 will be filled with arrays of index 1 (which was already filled because our for loop starts from the end)
  // The array at index 0 is our final multi-dim array

  // Goes from the before last SA to the first
  for (var current = dimensions.length-2; current !== -1; current--) {

    // Fills the current SA with index+1 SA
    for (var i = 0; i < arrays[current].length; i++) arrays[current][i] = arrays[current+1].slice(0)

  }

  // Returns first array, the complete one
  return arrays[0].slice(0)
}
```

My problem is that even if the array is well generated, some SA are passed by reference and not by value so when I do

```
my_array = generate([2, 4, 3])
my_array[1][2][1] = "hi!" // Fill a random place with "hi!"
```

Then when I do `console.log(my_array)`, some other cases of the multi-dim array are filled with the same value.
This means that somewhere, an array is passed by reference rather than passed by value which is strange
because I checked the code multiple times and I don't find where this could come from (I use the `Array.slice()`
method to "copy" the array)

Have I missed something huge?
Your help would be rather appreciated!

Comment: I think your issue is the use of `slice()`, which gives you a copy of the array, but not a copy of its elements.  You'd need to use something that gives you a deep copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, not sure how your trying to create your mult-dim array,..

But the first thing that springs to mind when seeing something like this, is recursion.

eg..

```js
function generate(dimensions) {
  if (!dimensions.length) throw new Error("no dims?");
  const dimsize = dimensions[0];
  if (dimensions.length === 1) {
    return new Array(dimsize).fill(null);
  }
  const ret = [];
  const subdims = dimensions.slice(1);
  for (let l = 0; l < dimsize; l+= 1) 
    ret.push(generate(subdims));
  return ret;
}

const my_array = generate([2, 4, 3])
my_array[1][2][1] = "hi!"

console.log(my_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I come up with this:

```js
function generate(dims) {
  if(dims.length > 0) {
    let array = new Array(dims[0]).fill(0);
    let childDims = dims.slice();
    childDims.shift();

    return array.map((el) => {
      return generate(childDims);
    });
  } else return 0;
}

let foo = generate([2, 3, 2]);
foo[0][0][1] = 'hmmmm';
console.log(foo);
```

Also using recursion to create multidimensional array. But when creating arrays as You saw, have to be carefull about not passing references but real copies of arrays. `Slice()` will give You only shallow copy.